# how to ignore IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#

I need something like this:

```
string a = "12345"
if (a[5] == null) {
    //skip error and continue the cycle
}
```

So the question is, how to ignore that type of error?

Comment: "how to ignore IndexOutOfRangeException?" **you should never ignore exceptions** - instead your program shouldn't cause them in the first place.

Comment: It would be better worded to "Fix an exception" rather than ignoring it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an additional length-check like:

```
if (a.Length >= 6 && a[5] == null) {}
```

but i think you mean something more like this:

```
if (a.Length >= 6 && a[5] == char.MinValue) {}
```

A char cannot be null. It can be '\0', which comes close to a "null".

Regards

Comment: `Char.Empty` is not a thing - are you thinking of `String.Empty`? (but that's irrelevant as a an element in a  `char[]`  cannot be "empty" nor `null` as it's a value-type)

Comment: I meant char.MinValue is '\0' as is i wrote in the above answer. '\0' comes close to something like "null" which the questioner really meant.